# Simple mysqli query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get simple info from a database and echo it to screen, but it's not working for me.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("SERVER.COM","USERNAME","PASSWORD", "DATABASE");

function GetTeamFixtures($team)
{
    $queryget = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM 'mlsfixtures' WHERE team='$team' LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryget);
    $gw1 = $row['gw1'];
    $gw2 = $row['gw2'];

    echo $team.' '.$gw1.' '.$gw2.'<br>';
}

$team = "Chicago Fire"; GetTeamFixtures($team);
$team = "Chivas USA"; GetTeamFixtures($team);
$team = "Colorado Rapids"; GetTeamFixtures($team);
//continue for all teams - removed for simplicity
```

Here are the error messages I get (line 46 is the $queryget= one and line 49 is the $row =  one).

`Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in server.com\teamfix.php on line 46`

`Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in server.com\teamfix.php on line 49`

Any idea why? I'm not sure if there's an easier way of doing the same thing but for 19 different teams.

Comment: By the way, you should use [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of PHP's string interpolation, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look into sorting that as soon as I get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to `$con` from within your function. This should work:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("SERVER.COM","USERNAME","PASSWORD", "DATABASE");

function GetTeamFixtures($team)
{
    global $con;
    $queryget = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `mlsfixtures` WHERE `team`='$team' LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryget);
    $gw1 = $row['gw1'];
    $gw2 = $row['gw2'];

    echo $team.' '.$gw1.' '.$gw2.'<br>';
}
```

**P.S.** If the `$team` you're passing in to `GetTeamFixtures` comes from user input, you should [prepare your statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Should I put the $con line inside the function? or is there a way of making it global?

Comment: `global $con;` gives you access to the global variable from within the function.

Comment: Thanks - I got this working. There were actually 2 things wrong with my code... It needed the backticks on `mlsfixtures` AND the global $con; part so thanks for that. I need to read up on the ticks as it's probably causing me problems elsewhere.

Comment: @Cully - Use single `'` (or double `"`) quotes to surround strings. Use backticks to surround table and column names.

Answer (score 2):

One of the errors i've found, aside from the two users that explained about connection, is the invalid use of single quotes.

Tables names should not be wrap with single quotes as they are identifiers and not a string literals. Remove the single quotes and it should work,

```
SELECT * FROM mlsfixtures WHERE team='$team' LIMIT 1
```

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks - yeah this is one of the problems I had - I put backticks there an it works fine now. Thanks for the injection tip. I knew it was vulnerable but I need to read up how to prevent it. It's not user input though so hopefully not as bad.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access variables outside a function instead of using `global variables` is to add it up in its parameters

E.g

```
function GetTeamFixtures($team,$con)
{
   // query inside
}
```

Also as `J W` says in your query remove '' or replace it with `` backticks..

Answer (score 1):

*(This is my attempt at combining all the other answers in a concise manner.)*

There are two problems.

First, the global variable `$con` is not accessible from within your function without a [`global` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global). The `global` statement can be used to create a [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) to `$con` from within your function.

```
global $con; // is equivalent to:
$con =& $GLOBALS['con'];
```

Second, the table name cannot be enclosed in single quotes. Remove the quotes.

```
// By the way, this should be using mysqli::prepare and mysqli_stmt::bind_param
// to prevent SQL injection
$queryget = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mlsfixtures WHERE team='$team' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$con` isn't visible within the function. If you want a global variable to be in scope in a function, you must declare it `global`:

```
function GetTeamFixtures($team) {
  global $con;
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this and removing the single quotes were what I needed to fix it.